# Book about a town plagued by werewolf and detective trying to figure out what is killing people

Tags: story-identification, novel, werewolf, detective

I am trying to find the name of a book that I read about 20 years ago when I was a teenager (yes, it’s an old book).

I don’t remember a lot from it, but basically there is a werewolf plaguing a town and a detective is on the case trying to figure out what is killing people.

Spoiler alert:

> It turns out the werewolf is actually the detective himself. He has no idea until the very end. I think he also ate his wife in the beginning, but this part I’m not sure on.

I am dying to read this book again, but can’t for the life of me remember the title or author.

Comment: "[...] 20 years ago when I was a teenager (yes, it’s an old book)." _Ouch, my aching bones._

Comment: @SQB - *Ouch, my aching bones* - Hold my beer: **listen, I am creaking when moving**... I was not a teenager anymore 20 years ago...

Comment: was browsing through story ID questions when someone said "it's an old book". My brain went like, how old? 1950s? 1870s? Nope. 2012. Apparently 2012 is old now....